# "On a more serious note" equivalent expression in Japanese

Tags: translation, idioms

At work, I would naturally use the above line as a transition. What equivalent phrases can I use in Japanese?

I could come up only with a quite literal translation:

> 真面目に言うと

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 「[真面目]{まじめ}に[言]{い}うと」

is ***not*** really the equivalent of "***on a more serious note***" in that the former cannot be used to introduce a new topic, which is what the latter is used for.

「真面目に言うと」 can only be used when you want to describe in a more serious manner the same thing that you have just described jokingly or half-jokingly.

If you want to move on from a non-serious topic to a rather serous one, you could say:

> 「（もう[少]{すこ}し or もっと or ちょっと）真面目な[話]{はなし}を**すると**」

or

> 「（もう少し or もっと or ちょっと）真面目な[話題]{わだい}に[変]{か}えると」

You could use 「シリアスな」 instead of 「真面目な」 with no problems.

Comment: Appreciate it, thanks for coming back on the details.

Answer (score 2):

真面目な話
マジな話 (slangy)

実に for this meaning is too old fashioned. I only see it in novels written in several decades ago.

Answer (score 2):

I like the expression "それより" which has the nuance of "more importantly..."

Answer (score 1):

Jitsu ni.

Informally speaking.